# Need help in Nihao Payment Gateway Integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

I am trying to use the Nihao payment method in my website. I have done everything. I generated the API Token from user area http://betatms.aurfy.com . It is still giving the error like this

```
{"code":500,"label":"81","message":"merchant config error"}
```

I am unable to find the error. I have correctly updated the config.php. I am using this API in cutom PHP templates.

The config.php code is given below

```
/**
 * Merchant config file 
 * Please read doc/README.txt first
 */
ini_set('date.timezone','UTC');

$server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$uri = 'http'.(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '').'://'.$server;
//set demo php path
//You can view your bearer token in the TMS by logging in and going to Settings -> Certificate -> View API Token.
define("TOKEN", "API Key will go here");

define("API_URL", "https://apitest.nihaopay.com/v1.2");//for test environment
//define("API_URL", "https://api.nihaopay.com/v1.1");//production environment

define("RETURN_URL", "https://www.zubairmushtaq.com/ppp/example/response/securepay_notify.php");
//you page return url Notice: Return Url can not be localhost

define("CALLBACK_URL", "https://www.zubairmushtaq.com/ppp/example/response/securepay_notify.php");
//you page callback url Notice: Callback Url can not be localhost


Nihao Website: http://nihaopay.com
Documentation: https://docs.nihaopay.com/api/v1.2/en
PHP API: https://github.com/nihaopay/nhpapi_demo
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code that is returning your error.

Comment: Question is updated. Thanks

Comment: Where is the code that is actually making the call? I just see definitions

Answer (score 0):

There were some configuration error from the Payment GateWay company. I requested them to update configuration. Now, the problem is solved. Thanks.